# When UIWebView frame changed, the scrollView changed too, how can I only change the frame?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a question about `UIWebView` in xcode, the sample code is given below, add this into a `UIWebView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, 768, 1024);
    [webview.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 5000)];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.baidu.com"]]];
    webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}

- (IBAction)button2pressed:(id)sender {
    webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, 768, 1024);
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",webview.scrollView.contentSize.height,webview.scrollView.contentSize.width);
}

- (IBAction)button1pressed:(id)sender {
    webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 300, 768, 1024);
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",webview.scrollView.contentSize.height,webview.scrollView.contentSize.width);
}
```

After I press `button1` and `button2` the answer is all `5000,768`.

But when I change the size `(0,300,768,1024)` to `(0,300,768,1044)` then the answer changed to `1024,768` and `1044,768`, it means the scrollview's `contentSize` changed.

Who can tell me how can I change the webview's size without change the scrollview's size? I use xcode 4.3.2 and IOS SDK 5.1.

I find that if I change the size to `(0,300,200,200)` and use 'www.qq.com' then it seems the answer is always 4218,1000 unless I change the rectangle size large than (4218,1000). So I think there are some parameters stored in the webview or the scrollview to control the minimum size of scrollview. Who knows the parameters I am searching for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the content size in the `viewdidload` before & after the `loadRequest`.

Then Do the same after changing the frame, that should answer your question.